# What is this symbol

Tags: symbol

Can you please advice what is the symbol in red in following wiring diagram.

[image]

Comment: "Burner Reset" is almost certainly a thermal limit switch with manual reset. It will cut out if its design temperature is exceeded.

Comment: It looks like an external reset switch that is poorly documented.   https://www.ferroli.com/media/1492008768.pdf

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It looks like an external reset switch that is poorly documented.   Yet defined as **BURNER RESET**. This is a **Ferroli wood pellet burner furnace**. https://www.ferroli.com/media/149200876/8.pdf  I assume it is used after fault maintenance is repaired.  Call them and ask.  800 596040  Tel: +39 045 6139411
Fax: +39 045 6100933

prevendita@ferroli.com
info@ferroli.com